# UIPickerView - can I have an image next to the text on each row?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'd like to have an image next to the text on each row of a pickerview, as you can with cells in a Table View.  Is this possible?

Specifically I'm trying to put a tick or arrow next to the currently selected row to indicate it as selected rather than have the transparent bar over the top which just looks messy... Don't have any code to post yet as I'm a bit lost with it, but I assume it would be in viewForRow?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, you can use the `- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` to pass your custom `UIView` of the `UIPickerView`. Also take this point in consideration:

> **Return Value**
>
> > The view provided by the delegate in the
> >     pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: method. Returns nil if
> >     the specified row of the component is not visible or if the delegate
> >     does not implement pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, so I need to create a custom view - that's another new task for me to learn!!! Thanks, are there any good guides to setting up custom views, as I could probably use that for a number of things...?

Comment: Maybe this link could help :) http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view